# How to show this $ \frac{{(2)}^{2n}{0.5}^{(4n+3)}}{(4n+3)(2n+1)!} $ tends to 0 as $n$ approaches infinity?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{{(2)}^{2n}{0.5}^{(4n+3)}}{(4n+3)(2n+1)!} $$

Anyone can suggest me any larger f(x) to be used for squeeze theorem to conclude this limit is 0? And please explain how you get the f(x) so that I know how to find next time for this type of question.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$\left| \frac{{(2)}^{2n}{0.5}^{(4n+3)}}{(4n+3)(2n+1)!} \right|\leq{(2)}^{2n}{0.5}^{(4n+3)}\leq 4^n \times \frac 1{4^{2n}} = \frac 1{4^n},\quad n\geq 1.$$